# Why are the parameters of my encoder and decoder not symmetric in my autoencoder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement an autoencoder in Tensorflow using the Keras API. My code is inspired by examples on the Keras website: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

The goal is to be able to detect outliers in a data set by measuring the reconstruction error. My code looks like the following (I removed some layers to make it fit better):

```
inputD = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1602,))
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal' )(inputD)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(encoded)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(encoded)
encoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(encoded)

decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(encoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(decoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(decoded)
decoded = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1602, activation='sigmoid', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(decoded)


autoencoder = tf.keras.Model(inputD, decoded)
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='binary_crossentropy',  metrics=['mse'])

autoencoder.summary()
```

This results in the following model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         (None, 1602)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              1641472   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 8200      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 36        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 3)                 15        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 16        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 8)                 40        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              9216      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 1602)              1642050   
=================================================================
Total params: 3,301,045
Trainable params: 3,301,045
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I don't understand why my parameters aren't symmetric, I would expect the shapes of the weight matrices of, for example, the last layer be the same as the input layer but this is not the case. Is this normal?

As I was typing this I thought it could be because of the biases in the hidden layers. If I set `use_bias=False` I do get mirrored parameters, but I'm not sure what is most common to use? Should the encoder and decoder have mirrored parameters in order to get better performance?

Answer (score 0):

As you already thought the problem here are the biases. If you take for example the weights between Dense 12 and Dense 13 you have `1024*8 = 8192` normal weights + `8` biases (`8200` in total).

If you take the weights between Dense 17 and 18 you'll have `8*1024 = 8192` normal weights + `1024` biases (`9216` in total). You'll always have as many biases as you have neurons in the next layer.

Hope that answers your question.